# 'subtle' difference in Sylow's theorem between notes and text

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Question:If a group of order $5^{2}\cdot 7 \cdot 11$ has at least one Sylow 5-Subgroup, exactly how many does it has?

My past notes uses a different approach to this; in particular, it says that for a group of order $p^{k}m$ where $p\in\mathbb{P}, k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and p does not divide m: the number of Sylow p-subgroup is 1 mod p and divides the order of m.
This is very different to the theorems in a text I'm relying on.

My text says: the number of of Sylow p-subgroup is 1 mod p and divides the order of G. It does not specify the 'form' of the order of G.

Attempt:

$5^{2}$ divides order of G so G has at least one subgroup of order $5^{2}$; in particular, this subgroup is a Sylow 5-subgroup and there is at least one of it in G.

I would like to know how I can build on the theorem used by my text.

Comment: What's $n$?  you have the order of $G$ as $p^km$ but then you write in terms of the undefined $n$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I've edited it. "n" ought to be prime p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the Sylow subgroups are all conjugate (this is another Sylow theorem).  Therefore, if $H$ is a Sylow subgroup of $G$, then the index $[G:N(H)]$ of the normalizer $N(H)$ in $G$ is the number of Sylow subgroups.  However, since $N(H)$ contains $H$ as a subgroup, this means that this index is relatively prime to $p$ and divides the $m$ part of $|G|=p^km$ (without having to write $m$).

Comment: I don't quite understand the part regarding how the normaliser of H plays a role in conjugacy.
Does this come from a theorem?

Comment: The real basis for the relationship comes from the theory of group actions.  Here's the idea though: For each $a\in N(H)$, $aHa^{-1}=H$, so $N(H)$ is the set of elements of $G$ that don't change $H$ under conjugation.  The remaining elements all do change $H$ under conjugation.  However, some of them change $H$ to the same conjugate subgroup.  In fact, $g_1Hg_1^{-1}=g_2Hg_2^{-1}$ if and only if $g_2^{-1}g_1\in N(H)$, i.e., $g_2$ and $g_1$ define the same coset of $N(H)$.  Therefore, the cosets of $N(H)$ correspond to the Sylow-$p$ subgroups and the index is the number of cosets.

Comment: It's a good exercise to show that for any subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, the map $xN_G(H) \mapsto xHx^{-1}$ is a bijection from the set of left cosets of $N_G(H)$ in $G$ onto the set of subgroups of $G$ which are conjugate to $H$.

Comment: Theorem 3:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems
And yes I should show this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=p^km$ with $\gcd(m,p)=1$ be the order of $G$. Then these two conditions are equivalent:

- $n_p \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and $n_p$ divides $n$
- $n_p \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and $n_p$ divides $m$

Indeed, $n_p \equiv 1 \bmod p$ implies $\gcd(n_p,p)=1$ and so if $n_p$ divides $n=p^km$, then $n_p$ divides $m$.

So, in your example, $n_5$ divides $7 \cdot 11$ and  $n_5 \equiv 1 \bmod 5$. The only possibility is $n_5=11$.

Comment: What is your motivation for assuming that the order of G is $p^{k}m$? Does this rely on Michael's reasoning?

Comment: @Mathematicing Every integer can be factored as $p^km$ for some $k\geq 0$ where $m$ and $p$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @Mathematicing, that's what I read in your question. Perhaps the notes are missing the point that $\gcd(m,p1)=1$.

Comment: There are definitely details missing in the notes. It makes me uncomfortable which is why I'm relying on a text.